# Subsidiary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, cauchy-problem

I was presented with the equation:

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{dx}{x(x+y)} = \frac{dy}{y(x+y)} = \frac{dz}{(x-y)(2x+2y+z)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

So, we immediately know that the solution must be in this form:

$F(c_1,c_2) =0$.

Taking the the first two terms:

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(x+y)}{x(x+y)} = \frac{y}{x}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{}{\frac{1}{x}} \ dx =\int_{}{\frac{1}{y}} \ dy
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Then,

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\ln {\frac{x}{y}} => \frac{x}{y} = c_1
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

**The solution:**
$\frac{x}{y} = c_1$

Next,

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{dx - dy}{(x-y)(x+y)}= \frac{dz}{(x-y)(2x+2y+z)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Finally subtracting and multiplying by a factor of $(x-y)$ (on both sides),

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{dx-dy-dz}{(-x-y+z)} = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

**The solution is:**
$\frac{x}{yz^2} =c_2$
So, The solution is $F(\frac{x}{y},\frac{x}{yz^2}) =0$

Am I correct?

Comment: How did you get $x-y$ in the argument of $F$ from $c_{1} = x/y$?

Comment: @Mattos sorry about that

Comment: Please tell again why $z^2y/x$ is a constant of the characteristic curves. The present equations seem not to support this. Is there a typo in the third fraction?

Comment: @LutzL Because in general, when taking the integral of some function, there exist a constant. Although the equation equals zero, by subtracting the constant on both sides, equals a still equals a constant. Hopefully you get what I’m saying lol

Comment: No, your argument is still false. From $\frac AB=\frac CD$ you can conclude $\frac AB=\frac{A-C}{B-D}=\frac CD$, but not $\frac{A-C}{B-D}=0$. So you get $\frac{d(x-y)}{x+y}=\frac{d(x-y-z)}{-x-y-z}$.

Comment: @LutzL Ahh! I see!

Comment: @LutzL Wait! I did that though. dx-dy=dz.

Comment: No, that is wrong. You have $(2x+2y+z)d(x-y)=(x+y)dz$, which is not the same.

Comment: @LutzL After I cancelled out (x-y), I subtracted again

Comment: @LutzL which is why I got dx-dy-dz as the numerator

Comment: @LutzL can I not do that?

Comment: Yes, I added the resulting relation to my first comment. You made a sign error, and the fraction of the differences is not the difference of the fractions, thus not zero.

Comment: Along a characteristic curve $x$ can be chosen as parameter, you found $y=ax$. Then 
$$
\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{(1−a)(2x+2ax+z)}{x(1+a)}=2(1-a)+\frac{1-a}{1+a}\frac zx
$$
and that can be solved as 1st order linear ODE, but with an ugly solution. Are you sure the original equations are correctly derived from the PDE?

Comment: @LutzL You just said that (A-C)/(B-D) =C/D. Is that not the difference of the fractions?

Comment: @LutzL Perhaps I’m just not understanding. The methods that which are used in the method of characteristics isn’t all that clear i.e. in this article http://ddeku.edu.in/Files/2cfa4584-5afe-43ce-aa4b-ad936cc9d3be/Custom/PARTIAL%20DIFFERENTIAL%20EQUATIONS%20Unit%20I%201-20.pdf, on page 10, you get a zero in the denominator.

Comment: @Lutz : I agree with your comments.  Especially when you asked "Is there a typo in the third fraction?". That was also what I supposed, since there was already several typos in is question. So, why not also a mistake in his system of ODEs ?  I asked DwightD to show the original PDE. He didn't edit it. Nevertheless, It is possible to fully solve the supposed PDE. The solution is a rather complicated formula. So, if the problem is a school problem, there is probably a typo or a mistake at very beginning.